# Receiving an error when installing MariaDB via pip3

Tags: pip, mariadb

Im receiving an error when installing mairadb via pip3. Below is the command and error.

```
sudo pip3 install mariadb
------------------------------------------------------------------
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting mariadb
  Using cached mariadb-1.0.0.tar.gz (78 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z5vslgxx/mariadb/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-z5vslgxx/mariadb/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-hfv4vge6
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-z5vslgxx/mariadb/
    Complete output (12 lines):
    /bin/sh: 1: mariadb_config: not found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-z5vslgxx/mariadb/setup.py", line 26, in <module>
        cfg = get_config(options)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-z5vslgxx/mariadb/mariadb_posix.py", line 49, in get_config
        cc_version = mariadb_config(config_prg, "cc_version")
      File "/tmp/pip-install-z5vslgxx/mariadb/mariadb_posix.py", line 26, in mariadb_config
        raise EnvironmentError(
    OSError: mariadb_config not found.
    Please make sure, that MariaDB Connector/C is installed on your system, edit the configuration file 'site.cfg' and set the 'mariadb_config'
    option, which should point to the mariadb_config utility.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I have updated setuptools for pip via `sudo pip3 install --upgrade setuptools`  to no avail. This error also occurs when trying to install most sql related modules for example mysql.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+mariadb_config+not+found

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am now able to install MariaDB 1.0.0 (and above) connector with no issues now. If you are receiving an OS error, install the mariadbclient-dev package with `sudo apt-get install libmariadb-dev` then you can install with `pip3 install mariadb`.

Comment: The package libmariadbclient-dev is no longer available, perhaps it has been obsoleted, instead of it I used libmariadb-dev and it works well for me.